# Why front Amazon AWS ElasticSearch with AWS Kinesis Firehose

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I see several applications where data is being sent to AWS Kinesis Firehose and then automatically transferred to AWS ElasticSearch. You can directly write to AWS ElasticSearch. If I don't need any kind of data transformation and I can directly write data to ElasticSearch does fronting ElasticSearch with AWS Kinesis Firehose still provide any advantage. Like does it protect ElasticSearch from spikes in traffic etc.?

Comment: FH is probably more secure option of adding data to FH from outside, then by making ES directly accessible from the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from transformations, the following reasons can be considered for having Firehose in front of AWS ES:

1. Better control over streaming data

Since Elasticsearch has limit on the write queue size, if there is a burst in data for few seconds, ES might throw rejects if it wont be
able to write the data in that limited data. In this, you will end
up **loosing the rejected data** as well.

However, when Firehose is kept in front, it will handle the retries for you and there will be less chances of data loss.

2. Firehose is one-way to ES

Your ES cluster might contain confidential data and if you are
allowing user to make POST requests (required for some writes), you
might expose the cluster to more than required users. Firehose can
help you in limiting that by only giving write applications/user
access to the FH stream instead of the ES cluster.